# Не запускается mysql в ubuntu

Tags: mysql

После переустановки не запускается mysql в ubuntu.

Выдаёт:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect tolocal MySQL server through socket'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Директория `/var/run/mysqld` отсутствует

`netstat -na | grep 3306` - ничего

```
find / -name mysqld* /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow /usr/bin/mysqldump /usr/sbin/mysqld /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldumpslow.1.gz /usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8.gz
```

Видимо проблема с установкой....

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install mysql-server Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done mysql-server is already the newest version. You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: mysql-server: Depends: mysql-server-5.0 but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

На vps стоит старая убунту 9.0 и mysql 5.0

Пробую: `apt-get -f install`

> Errors were encountered whileprocessing:/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.0_5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.5_i386.debE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returnedan error code (1)

что делать?

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться aptitude - она чуть лучше решает проблемы с зависимостями, ну и `apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

Обращайтесь к хостеру VPS лучше

Answer (score 1):

по пробуйте выполнить команду

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

потом

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```